# How to convert char array to String in arduino?

Tags: arduino-ide, c++

I want to convert const char array in PROGMEM to String. How do I do this?

```
const char charArray[] PROGMEM = "Some text";
```

Comment: If you mean a C++ style string, I think you just need to do this - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8960087/how-to-convert-a-char-array-to-a-string

Comment: No, I want to convert this in Arduino-IDE. That is not work correctly!

Comment: I just saw the answer and I had no idea that was even possible. I think that is your answer.

Comment: Unfortunately that is not work. Thank you, however.

Comment: what does this mean? `that is not work`  ....   that statement provides no useful information ....  describing the actual error would help

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you can use a cast to `__FlashStringHelper` to invoke the right constructor of the String class. It is the constructor which copies the char array from PROGMEM. `__FlashStringHelper` is intended as return type for the F() macro.

```
const char charArray[] PROGMEM = "Some text";

void setup() {

  Serial.begin(115200);

  String s((const __FlashStringHelper*) charArray);

  Serial.println(s);
}

void loop() {
}
```

Comment: That is right, but how do this in loop or another functions?

Comment: PROGMEM is always global. and setup() is a function like every other so same way

Comment: Absolutely, but when I write this code in loop, the compiler will generate this error:
conflicting declaration 'String s'

Comment: Thanks so much. The compiler error was due to another part of my sketch.